ngx-editor edit mode does not display properly
I am using ngx-editor for my use case. Edit mode is not working fine but it is giving extra breaks and UL and LI do not display properly like below. I am using default styling and tags. Not sure what is the issues, All the examples I have seen it works properly.

I see that this is happening because of ../../node_modules/@clr/ui/clr-ui.min.css inclusion in angular.json file. How do I prevent its impact?
